# how to specify the accracy of navigation-based on GPS OR SLAM?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

I have the output of navigation based on gps, i mean global odometry information (/odometry/filtered_map), and SLAM odometry information output. Now how can i specify the accuracy of this system?
How to specify the accuracy of the system?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392574/how-to-specify-the-accracy-of-navigation-based-on-gps-or-slam?/) by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2021-12-22**:
Are you trying to compare the SLAM solution to the GPS solution?

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2021-12-22**:
thanks @ Tom Moore
actually, i don't have any ground truth to compare the global filtered-map(output of ekf-global) , and slam odometry information with that one. so I want to specify the accuracy of my global odometry, and slam odometry information with GPS data(considered as ground truth). how can i do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand you correctly, you have a source of ground truth data and your EKF-filtered state, and you want to compare them so as to quantify the accuracy of the EKF-filtered state.

If it were me, I'd compute the transform between the first pose in your EKF-filtered state (`nav_msgs/Odometry` message) and the first pose in your ground truth. Then I'd subscribe to the EKF filtered state, transform it into the frame of your ground truth, and then just compare them directly.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2022-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0